# Can't connect Windows Mobile 6.1 to Windows Mobile Center

Tags: windows-mobile, activesync, windows-mobile-6.1

I have a Windows Mobile 6.1 device that I need to connect to Windows Mobile Center via Blutooth.

Note: **The same steps Works with a Windows Mobile 5.1 device in the same computer, and I tested with two different computers.**

1. I can pair the PC and the PDA without problem.
2. In the PC I run Windows Mobile Center.
3. In the PDA I run ActiveSync and select "Connect via Bluetooth".
4. The PDA open a window with the text "Openning port...".
5. The text changes to "User authenticated".
6. The window closes, and a full screen message with title "Synchronization Error" and text "This device is not allowed to connect to desktop computer" appears.

The PDA is a new and clean device.
The computer isn't connected to Active Directory Domain. It has Windows 7 (the two computers tested)

I thing this is a security configuration, but I can't disable or grant access. The pair Works without any error, and I can see the pair settings on the PC and on the PDA.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I assume you have enabled Bluetooth conection in WMDC Connection settings on the PC too. For more troubleshooting please try: Some logging for WMDC on your PC:
http://www.pocketpcfaq.com/faqs/wmdc/debug/index.htm

Some more articles about AS/WMDC troubleshooting:
http://www.pocketpcfaq.com/faqs/activesync/usb-advanced-functionality.htm
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/915152

Comment: Thanks for your info @Josef, the logs don't seems to reveal nothing, also I tested with USB cable with the same result, and test on two different computers. I thing there is a security lock on the device.

Comment: Did you pair using an USB cable? Can you connect using Bluetooth settings on the device; searching for nearby devices, connecting to your PC?

Comment: I pair the devices with Bluetooth, then try to connect with "Connect via Bluetooth" option in PDA's ActiveSync, with a WM5.1 Works. Another try is to connect via USB (no pair needed). I can connect with WM5.1 via USB, but the same error with WM6.1

Comment: Possibly one of the sync settings on the PC are not permitted (ie access directory or to mail), try by disabling all syncing on the PC. There are alos locked-down devices, what model is the WM6.1 one.

Comment: I try to connect as guest device, but I have no option to setup, WMDC don't show any message or window. The device is a PIDION BIP-1300 industrial device with Windows Mobile 6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the problem was that the device was locked for security. The manufacturer sent me a cab to disable security, which in this case only annoyed.

If someone has the same problem, send me an email to duefectu(a)sd-a.com and I will forward the file.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The cab may only work for this device as they use private certificate.

Comment: Sure that only work on PIDION devices or PIDION BIP-1300